# Function to check list of lists have all integer elements between 0 and n and lists are all of given length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to check the following for the list of tuples:

C = [[2, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0, 3]]
D = [[2, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 0, 3]]

I want to check if the list is of length n where n>0 and is an integers and that list has lists of length n as well. 
Check the entries are integers between 0 and n-1

CONDITIONS:

- list is of length n
- list only has number elements  lists inside
- lists within the list are of length n
- lists inside have elements between 0 and n-1
- elements of lists are all integers

so, for C it would be the list is of length 4, it has lists with length 4 and all are integers between 0 and 4, so the function should output true.

For D it would be false, as the list has length 3 while lists within have length 4.

Can anyone please help?

I have tried the isinstance command but my code is becoming very messy with a lot of them. Is there an easier way of doing this ?

This is what I have so far, it is not complete.

```
def checklist(X):
    n = len(X) #check len
    n = int #check it is int
    if n>0: #condition n>0 
        if isinstance(X,list): #check if x is list 
            for i in range(n) :
                if isinstance(X[i],list): #check if the X contains list 
                   a = X[[i]]
                   if isinstance(a, int)
```

Comment: Thats a list of lists not a list of tuples...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the term. Ammended the question now. Thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend focusing on readability and simplicity for something like this. It's easy to get lost when trying to satisfy multiple conditions, and harder to figure out what you were doing when you come back to the code later if you try to be clever, or as concise as possible. If you make the requirements separate and explicit you can more easily see that you're testing them properly. Early returns can keep your code less indented and easier to read as well.

```py
def element_is_good(element, length):
    return isinstance(element, int) and 0 <= element < length

def sublist_is_good(sublist, length):
    return (isinstance(sublist, list)
            and len(sublist) == length
            and all(element_is_good(element, length) for element in sublist))

def list_of_lists_is_good(list_of_lists):
    n = len(list_of_lists)
    return n > 0 and all(sublist_is_good(sublist, n) for sublist in list_of_lists)
```

This is a bit longer than the other solutions, but I would argue it is easier to read, easier to test thoroughly, and more maintainable. (It also satisfies *all* the requirements you listed; [DroiX86's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669509/9200529) will accept an empty list or a list of dictionaries, and [kmario23's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669647/9200529) will accept an empty array or a list of tuples. I omitted your "n is an int" requirement because the len function only returns ints.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated. I agree with the readibility especially as a beginner, the short hand code is difficult to understand.

Comment: Hi I tried this and got the following error?? Out[2]: <generator object  list_of_lists_is_good.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x00000224A252FE58>

Answer (score 4):

Use a nested `all` with nested list comprehension

```
C = [[2, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0, 3]]

n = 4

def is_valid(C, n):
    valid_values = range(n)
    return all(all(x in valid_values for x in l) and len(l) == n for l in C) and len(C) == n

print is_valid(C, n)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I incorporate this into a function?

Comment: @NewYork `def foobar(C, n): return all(all(x in range(n) for x in l) and len(l) == n for l in C)`. Though you should pick better naming conventions then a single letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, till now I didn't see the need.

Comment: I can't include n as a variable so I did the following def foobar(C, n): n = len(X)
    return all(all(x in range(n) for x in l) and len(l) == n for l in C) However I get a generator error. @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Also, can I ask what 'x in l' is referring to exactly?

Comment: What the heck is `X`? You probably mean to use ` def foobar(X):` That being said **use meaningful variables names**. Don't just use a letter because it works. It is an extremely bad coding practice.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Sorry, that was C. n = len(C) My apologies.

Comment: Thank you so much @DroidX86. Thats a great help, appreciated. However if I alter the code by writing n = len(arr) so there is only one variable i.e the list, does not work. For example, the code needs to work a list like [[1,2,0], [1,2,2]] and written false as all conditions are satisfied except the length of list being length of lists inside i.e. 3.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the last part

Comment: I have ammended the question to make it more clear. I am meaning that for a list of size 2 and lists within the list are of size 3, the condition of len(list) and len(lists within list) is not satisfied as in the example in the comment, the length of the list is 2, the lengths of lists within are length =3 so they don't match.

Comment: Guess i missed the first condition - edited it in just now

Answer (score 2):

Since this has been tagged with NumPy, here is a NumPy-only solution:

```
# input for positive case
C = [[2, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0, 3]]
c_arr = np.array(C)  # convert to numpy array

# input for negative case
D = [[2, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 0, 3]]
d_arr = np.array(D)

# range to check for
n = 4
```

Incorporating all needed conditions inside Python function (as needed by OP):

```
def check_condition(n, arr):
     if arr.shape[0] == n and np.all(arr >= 0) \
        and np.all(arr < n) and arr.dtype == np.int:
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

---

```
# checking for positive case        
check_condition(n, c_arr)   # returns `True`

# checking for negative case        
check_condition(n, d_arr)   # returns `False`
```